# Registering a third party package in a Vue project when using typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-class-components

I installed a package in my vue.js project that I created using vue-cli and I am using typescript with it. The package is for social authentication for google. https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-google-oauth2

Now, when I imported the package in my main.ts file, it would give and error as follows:

Could not find a declaration file for module 'vue-google-oauth2'. implicitly has an 'any' type.

> Try `npm install @types/vue-google-oauth2` if it exists or add a new
>   declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module
>   'vue-google-oauth2';`

I got rid of the error by simply adding the line `declare module 'vue-google-oauth2';` in my shims.d.ts file. However, now that this issue is resolved, I am still getting another error in my terminal even though the application works fine. The new error is as follows:

> Property '$gAuth' does not exist on type 'AuthMixin'

basically I am using this.$gAuth and even though it is working, the terminal still says that it does not exist in my vue instance. How can I make this error go away?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how `vue-google-oauth2` works but I assume it adds global mixin with getter `$gAuth`. In this case you have 2 options:

Declare types for `$gAuth`:

```
declare module 'vue/types/vue' {

    interface Vue {
        $gAuth: any; // or specify gAuth type if .d.ts is provided
    }
}
```

Or use objec key syntax:

```
this['$gAuth']() // or w/e you use to call it
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much for the answer but unfortunately I'm still kind of lost. The mixin is actually my own. I made the mixin and am using the vue-google-oauth2 package which I register in my vue instance in the main.ts file. so this.$gAuth should work just as this.$store works. But that is not the case. and your solution isn't exactly resolving the error

Comment: Please provide all the code, Mixin + how you call it and the code where it fails, and the error stacktrrace. Is this a compile error?

Comment: Typescript has to be specifically informed that $gAuth exists on the Vue instance, the declaration above *should* cover it for compilation because as you have said it is there at runtime. If it's not working there's a slightly different interface I use as well as this one.

Comment: Ok I've edited my question to also include part of the authMixin code. As you can see, the code runs fine at runtime it just gives an error in my terminal that this.$gAuth does not exist. However, this.$http does not give any such error. so I can't seem to figure out how I'm supposed to declare gAuth properly and where I'm supposed to do it